# refresh to same element javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thanks for reading. I'm pretty new to Javascript/Jquery and know the real problem is being able to search for or ask the correct question.

I'm trying to make a single page website from a preexisting multiple page website.

My problem is when refreshed the page, of course, reverts to its index.html.
Websites I have seen that don't have this problem seem to use a hash function. Is this the key? Are there any resources I should look at for this?

Thanks.

Example:

```
var main = (function() {
    //changes colour of activated submenu//
    `$('.topnav ul li a').click(function(){`

    $('.topnav ul li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });

//hides all but activated submenu's content//
    $('#topnav-ea').click(function(){
      $('#arrivals').show()
      $('#company-profile').hide();
      $('#contact-info').hide();
    });

    $('#topnav-cp').click(function(){
      $('#arrivals').hide();
      $('#company-profile').show();
      $('#contact-info').hide();
    });

    $('#topnav-ci').click(function(){
      $('#arrivals').hide();
      $('#company-profile').hide();
      $('#contact-info').show();
    });
});

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: You may find it easier to use a framework that specialises in single-page-apps, such as angular, instead of jquery. It has built in support for routing, which is what you're looking for

Comment: @louis I hope I understood your question correctly!! for each link you have, you should have an href which identifies what is the status of your current page.  you can check angular routing system which has the same methodology

Comment: Are the backticks at the beginning and end of your 3rd line an error that happend when you copied your code in here?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes the backticks were a copied error, thanks for the keen eye!

Comment: @msoliman, the href for the submenus are all set as #, I don't understand how one can store position ona  page when it is refreshed.

Comment: @user184994, I think studying angular would be a good move, thank you.